# RH 7.9 facing dependency error while yum update (libpcre and libquadmath)

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I am currently updating my RH 7.9 and facing 2 dependency errors.
Could anyone assist ?
Thanks in advance!

```
Error: Package: grep-2.20-6.el6.x86_64 
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64 
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64
              ~libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
              ~libpcre16.so.0()(64bit)
              ~libpcre32.so.0()(64bit)
```

and

```
Error: Package: libgfortran-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 
           Requires: libquadmath = 4.8.5-44.el7
           Removing: libquadmath-4.8.5-44.el7.i686 
               libquadmath = 4.8.2-16.el7
               libquadmath = 4.8.5-44.el7
```

Comment: Why are there RHEL 6 packages installed on this system? What is it really?

Comment: Hi Michael , it was handed to me after the previous admin left without any notes or whatever so I am not sure but I am guessing it is an upgrade from RHEL6 -> 7

Comment: A not very well done upgrade, it seems. OK, I would start recovering with `yum --skip-broken distro-sync` (post the complete output from this command). This will attempt to replace existing packages with the current versions in the repos, whether it's an upgrade or downgrade, but will skip any that have dependency problems it can't solve. There will probably be more that needs to be done after that, depending on what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues but after I removed both **(in my case) net-snmp-libs and net-snmp-utils**; I was able to update the server. I ran a `yum erase command`. I should have check to see if after removing one of the packages would the error go away.

```
 yum -y erase net-snmp-utils yum -y erase net-snmp-libs.
```

see also:
 [known issues section](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7.1908#head-6f9ba2dc7641930cf0dd387ee518d4565f8e5c2e)